Texture animation with math nodes
starting from a texture image (B&W), I'd like to animate the movement of the white line by limiting its movement between the two black lines. Would a math node allow me to do this?
I'm attaching a images to explain what I mean, and a sample image on which I'd like to run this animation.
Thanks to anyone who takes the time to look at this post.



EDIT :
Maybe I misspoke. I put a video that may be more relevant.
My goal is to animate the texture in relation to the rotation of my object. I've already created the variable related to rotation and I'd like to attach it to math nodes to animate it.


EDIT :
I'm adding the blend I'm testing. To answer StephLAncien. The X rotation works with the geometry node and the attribute is retrieved from the shader. I'm now trying to animate the texture correctly.

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/, including the animation of the object ? It is to understand how the Shader could be informed of the rotation of the object...

SetfLAncien, I edited the post and added the current blend.

if you change your uv in that way, that the face covers the whole uv map (from 0 to 1) you can use this node setup:

and animate the position of the white slider in the colorramp:


Thanks for your reply.
I tried to use a coloramp but later, I need to use the rotation value of my object to animate the image. I would like to avoid using a driver in the coloramp to control this.
Tell me, if I'm not expressing myself well ^^

so can you pls elaborate your "end goal"? would be great if you add all details we need to the question so we know what you "really" want. thx.
